# about powers of gradient operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

Let u be a smooth function and ∇ is the gradient operator in n dimensions such that $\nabla^2 u=\Delta u$ is obvious. However, if we set D=$(\partial_t,∇)$ as a PDE operator in $(n+1)$ dimensions, which yields $Du=(∂_tu,∇u)$ when applied to $u$. What are meanings of the noations $D^2u$ or $D^\alpha u$ or $∇^\alpha u$ for $|α|=k$ (partial derivatives of order k). It looks like multi-index notaion but $D$ and $\nabla$ are vectors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$D^2$ usually means the "scalar product" of the "vector" $D$ with itself, so $D^2 = \partial_t^2+\Delta$ (assuming you're not working on some manifold with some specific metric, but let's not get lost in there).

$D^\alpha$ usually indicates the "multiindex power", that is:
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^{(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)} = x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot x_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n^{\alpha_n}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the right-hand side of the last equality  must be product of them not sum (From Renardy's PDE book). Why dont we define $D^2$ as $\partial_t^{\alpha_0}\nabla^{\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n}$ for $\alpha=(\alpha_0,...,\alpha_n)$ in the same manner as the last equality.

Comment: Also do you have an idea for powers of $\nabla$

Comment: @user40615 You're correct about the fact that they have to be products, I edited my answer. What do you mean by "products of $\nabla$"? If you mean things like $\nabla^3$ and so on, then it should be $\nabla^3 = \nabla\Delta = \Delta\nabla$ (mixed partials commute for smooth enough functions).

Comment: I mean $\nabla^\alpha u=?$ for $\alpha= (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$ with $|\alpha|=\alpha_1+\cdots\alpha_n$. For instance, what is the result when $|\alpha|=2$. Also how we define $D^\alpha u$, where $D= (\partial_t, \nabla)$ when $|\alpha|=2$.

Comment: @user40615 If $\alpha$ is a multiindex, $|\alpha| = 2$ means that the sum of the element of $\alpha$ gives $2$. An example of such an $\alpha$ is $\alpha = (1,0,0,1)$ In this case, if you have $3$ spatial dimensions, $D^\alpha = \partial_t\partial_{x^3}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation I think I got it. I was confusing the integer and multi-index powers of $D$. Similarly, $\nabla^\alpha$ should be equal to $\partial_{x_1}^{\alpha_1} \partial_{x_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots\partial_{x_n}^{\alpha_n}$. Do you agree?

Comment: @user40615 Yes. I think you got the concept.

Comment: Evan's PDE text has an appendix describing clean notation for PDEs. You might want to check it out.